# D3DX11EffectsD.lib not showing up after build (vs2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx

I am starting to learn DX11 and running into trouble with the effects framework. I know it was released as source and I have to build it, but the output from the build is not what I expected. 
According to the research I've done on this question, the output from the build should be 
D3DX11EffectsD.lib for debug
D3DX11Effects.lib for release

However, when I look into the 'Effects11\Debug' directory after building the project, I only see a file Effects11.lib (well, an Effects11 Object Library file which I assume is a .lib, I'm new to c++), and the exact same file in 'Effects11\Release'. Whats going on here? I've never used VS 2010 for c++ before now but I think I am building the solution correctly.

Is this a matter of renaming the files or have I done something wrong without realizing it? There really isn't much documentation on building and linking libraries in vs 2010 that I could find. Anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled exactly what you got off the web, then I *think* it would be just a naming convention problem.

You should try compiling it into your end application and see if it yells about debugging symbols missing.

You can also go into the build settings (it has been a while since I have used visual studio for anything other than C# so I don't know exactly where that menu option would be (I assume right clicking on the project should yield some useful results)...I generally do my C++ stuff on linux) and check to see what the built targets are for debug and release. If it turns out that the names are the same for both, but the build targets (i.e. the folder and a few other options, like including debugging symbols) are different then you should be good and it is just a naming problem.

Also, if the files are the exact same size it is likely that they are the same since the debug file should be at least a bit larger than the release one.

If it turns out that they are the same file, try re-downloading or re-extracting the source and just compiling the project again without any changes and see if that gets any results.

Comment: Oddly, the debug file is less than half the size of the release file. I have no idea why that is. I'll try downloading it again. Thanks for the suggestions.